# display images with online source in foreach loop in php, repeating loop issue

Tags: php

I have A problem While displaying Images using foreach loop in php.
I am Passing Online http:// Source To The Image Tag
But My loop execute Only For One Time.
here is my code:
$popularmovies contain multiple values But loop execut only once.

```
<?php foreach ($popularmovies as $popmovies); ?>

<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo 'http://'.$popmovies- 
>Movie_cover; ?>" alt="" width="210" height="315" >

<? endforeach; ?>
```

this loop show only one image. but does not repeates.
help me please

Comment: The ; in `foreach ($popularmovies as $popmovies); ` should be a :

Comment: Not the issue here, but better to be consistent with opening tag style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($popularmovies as $popmovies): ?>

<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo 'http://'.$popmovies- 
>Movie_cover; ?>" alt="" width="210" height="315" >

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

...also check your `$popularmovies` array for length.

Comment: IMHO this question should be closed as a typo error, but if your going to give an answer can you at least explain what you've done which corrects the original problem.

Comment: @NigelRen You're right! But my english isn't so perfect to explain what I did, if I'll write in my native language Gulzar Ali will not understand.